# Zend Framework, PHP cURL, internal file to get raw contents parse over them and render them as a php file

Tags: php, file, zend-framework

Ok, not sure if this even the right logic for this. But what the end game that is planned is I need to come up with a method of retrieving contents of files within a given directory, and then output them as they would be if called up through normal conventions `include()`, `require()`, whatever.

The basis for this is, the sales team wishes the ability to edit specific help documents that can easily be added/removed/edited via FTP to a specific directory. However, this directory is out of bounds so to speak from the normal MVC logic, but still contained within the MVC install.

So with that I am trying to come up with a default template for them to work with that I can grab bits from between certain points and display it without using a database for this purpose. Ideas? I haven't tried anything yet just to save time for that question. I am looking for an idea or 2 to figure out how to start the process, which would be best means of tackling the issue at hand

Comment: I'd say you already named two good ideas. I see nothing wrong with them.

Comment: if it is inside your mvc install, why not simply create a "views" directory where the uploads are stored as .phtml? and use ->render() ?